# Handling optional data in Logistic regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working with data which contains marks and other features of students and trying to predict whether they will get a high salary or not using scikit-learn in python. I ran into a problem,
since a student does not take all the subject his/her score in a subject is -1 if he has not taken the subject (a student can take multiple subjects).

Below a snapshot taken from the data file:
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ivFD.png)

I am trying to find a way to interpret the -1 in a way that doesn't alter the data much.

My Approach:

1. Take the percentile marks for each student and then take the average of all percentiles for each student giving a single number for each student which a lot easier to work with but this method may lose some information about the distribution of marks.
2. Fill the -1 value with the average of marks for all the students in that subject, but this will not work if the data is biased towards one subject

Is there any better way the deal with this kind of data?

Comment: What's your *question*?

Comment: How to interpret the -1s in a way that doesn't alter the data.

Comment: Please edit & update your post to clarify this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your "-1"'s amount to missing data, so you are asking how to approach a classification task with missing data.  See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38986/should-i-use-missing-value-using-imputation-or-listwise-or-pairwise-deletion-met?rq=1) and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269128/is-it-appropriate-for-a-study-to-ignore-missing-data?rq=1), among many others, for discussions on this topic.

A couple important considerations that come to mind:

- One option is to "impute" the missing values, which is what you're describing with using "average marks."  This approach often requires the assumption that the data is "missing at random" which in your case is unlikely to be true: for example, a bad student is more likely to not take a difficult subject, so missing values tell you something.
- Using regression models (like logistic regression) are in general going to require some type of imputation.  But there are other models, like decision trees or Random forests, that can handle missing data without imputation.